# Linux Command > output.txt with delay

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

My issue is that when I run my script it continues past a command below:

```
top -b > output.txt
```

The data on machine is quite large and therefore it takes some time to retrieve the full stack of CPU stats from the `top` output. It outputs some instantly and then takes a little while to get the rest. (I checked by just running top command in terminal by itself).

I need to wait for all CPU stats etc to be retrieved (say 20 seconds), then grab the `top` output after 20 seconds is up and output to output.txt.

I know sleep is used for delays however it appears to be required somewhere specifically in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I very much doubts that a machine from this millennium will take 20 seconds to generate a single `top` table. More likely the issue is that you've told `top` to print output at intervals *forever*, and that output is not written immediately because of buffering. Try `top -b -n1 > output.txt` instead.

Comment: I will try this now, thanks.
I was exaggerating on the time, its more like a few seconds. 
Therefore in the instance of running the top -i -b -n 1 > output.txt, the cpu parts in the top section are not retrieved for a few seconds.
"top - 08:55:55 up 127 days, 18:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.49, 0.45
Tasks: 615 total,   1 running, 614 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.0%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.6%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st..."

Comment: Same issue still note that my command was already "top -i -n 1 - b > output.txt"

Answer (score -2):

Try using the `wait` command.

Like this:

```
top -bn 1 > output.txt & wait
```

It's supposed to wait until that process is complete before moving on.

Comment: That is pointless. First, `top -b` will never finish on its own, and second if it did finish on its own backgrounding it and then `wait`ing the same as simply running it in the foreground.

Comment: The `-b` switch is for batch mode and it is designed to be used this way. It does end. Run it yourself and see. I added "n 1" so it will only refresh once.

Comment: Now that you've added `-n1` it is the same as my answer except the pointless `wait`ing